How do I create an interactive chart with Metabase and MongoDB as data source?
I'm using Metabase as a data visualization tool, with MongoDB as the data source. I need to create a linechart from a query that performs a lookup between two collections.
Let's say I have the collections "companies" and "stockValues". Companies has the fields "_id" and "name"; StockValues has "_id", "price", "timestamp" and "companyId". The "companyId" field's values match those of the "_id" field in the "companies" collection, serving as a foreign key.
I want to plot on a line chart the stock prices trend for a given company. Specifically, I want  "stockValue.timestamp" to be on the x-axis, and "stockValue.price" on the y-axis. I also want to filter my query by "companies.name" and, optionally, by a date range.
This simple native query down here works. I'm doing an aggregate query starting from "companies" and pointing to "stockValues". Note the conversion from string to ObjectId for the field "companyId" of the Companies collection. It is needed because "companyId" in "stockValues" is of type string but the matching "_id" field in the "companies" collection is of type ObjectId.
Just for the record, if I weren't using Metabase, I would put the whole query inside a db.companies.aggregate() call. I'm using field filters for companyName and dateRange, hence the double parentheses.
[
    {
        $match: {{companyName}},
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "stockValues",
            let: { companyId: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
                [[{
                    $match: {{dateRange}},
                },]]
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: { $eq: ["$$companyId", { $toObjectId: "$companyId" }] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    $sort: {
                        "_id": -1
                    }
                }
            ],
            as: "stockValue"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$stockValue"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": false,
            "datetime": {"$toDate": "$stockValue.timestamp"},            
            "companyName": "$name",
            "stockId": "$stockValue._id",
            "stockPrice": "$stockValue.price"
        }
    }
]

The problem is that the chart I obtain is not interactive and, therefore, not very useful. I would like to have a zoomable chart so that users can easily view stock prices over time. As far as I know, what I am looking for is the drill-through capability. Could someone please tell me how to enable this feature or show me how to replicate the same query using Metabase graphical editor (i.e. without writing native code)? Thank you in advance.
